# UICollectionView supplementary view from child controller

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to implement layout displayed below (headers do scroll together with collection view, they are not pinned):

[image: Collection view layout]

By requirements `headerView1`, `headerView2`, `headerView3` and `collectionView` are controlled by separate controllers. 
So the hierarchy is:

```
MainViewController
  |
  - HeaderViewController1
  |
  - HeaderViewController2
  | 
  - HeaderViewController3
  |
  - CollectionViewController
```

I have managed to add `CollectionViewController` to `MainViewController` using child view controllers feature:

MainViewController.swift

```
func loadCollectionView() {
    let model = getModel()
    let collectionVC = CollectionViewController(withViewModel: model)
    addChildViewController(collectionVC)
    self.collectionVC = collectionVC
    collectionVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(collectionVC.view)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        collectionVC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        collectionVC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        collectionVC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        collectionVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
    collectionVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Header view controllers have similar initialisation in `MainViewController` but I can't find a way to display them as header views. It seems like supplementary view and `UICollectionReusableView` is way to go, but in my case I already have initialized view controllers and views. How would I add them to supplementary view?

What will be a good architecture here?

Comment: instead of CollectionViewController take only CollectionView in storyBoard or XIB it will be easy to manage your header view

Comment: By design all header views and collection views are separate controllers and do not share any storyboard. each of them have its own XIB file.